# Sampling video and making image cutoffs in python

Tags: python, image-processing, video-processing

I've got a videostream (for now I just use a video). I need to get a one frame per every second or more seconds and I need to cut some part of these pictures based on 8 coordinates(leftupper x/y, rightupper x/y, rightlower x/y and leftlower x/y).

I thinkg that I'm able to do that cutting in java but I would rather do it in python as entire application is written in python / django.

It's possible to do both of that things directly in python? 
Could you point me to some documentation or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with some Video Handling in Python Using OpenCV

[Python : Reading Video File and Saving Video File using OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

It contains all the basic links like Reading from File and Camera , that gives a initial idea of how to process Frames .

Then after you get Each Frame in OpenCV mat , you can form a Bounding Box Rect to extract the Region or ROI from that

Close to this Question
[Cropping Live Video Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296513/cropping-live-video-feed-in-opencv)

Cropping a Single Frame can be done as done in
[Cropping a Single Image in OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

This can be repeated for every Frame and you can even Write to a Video File taking reference from [First Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).